# Boton para depurar tabla phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Realizo un formulario y **lo que necesito hacer es hacer un botón que me depure mi tabla calculos** esto *con el fin de que este vacia mi tabla para que se inserten datos nuevos*, no se como hacerlo por medio de un boton en cambio si lo hago directo en SQL que es con la sentencia

**TRUNCATE TABLE calculos;**

Gracias.

Anexo la estructura de mi tabla:

```
id_Control       Primaria    Índice    int(10)  
idctg_turno      Índice                int(10)
total_horas                            int(10)    
horas_normales                         int(10)
horas_extras                           int(10)
Incidencia                             varchar(1000)
status                                 varchar(20)
```

Comment: Tendrías que lanzar una petición al servidor para que ejecute el comando en la base de datos. Esto se suele hacer por medio de Ajax, el cual invoca a un archivo PHP que se conecta a tu base de datos y ejecuta la sentencia `TRUNCATE TABLE calculos;`  ... Aquí hay varias respuestas sobre cómo funciona Ajax, revísalas en la [etiqueta `Ajax`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax?sort=votes&pageSize=50) y haz un intento de código basándote en alguna de ellas.